# Windows 10, with Linux Mint 18 in Hyper-V versus dual-boot

Tags: windows, windows-10, multi-boot, linux-mint, hyper-v

I'd like to run both Linux Mint 18 (Sarah) and Windows 10 Pro on my new Intel Core i7 machine. It already has Windows 10 installed, as that will be the primary OS. My first thought was to run Linux virtualized in Hyper-V, but in my research I have seen many references to dual-boot configurations.

The Hyper-V option seems to be the most advantageous for me, because:

1. I will be able to access both operating systems together, avoiding
   the need to reboot just to switch between them
2. My machine's specs are robust enough to be able to handle running
   the VM alongside my other Windows apps without issue

So far, I have not found any reason to prefer the dual-boot option. Does it seem like the virtualized option would be best for me, or is there some benefit to the dual-boot option I have overlooked?

Comment: In the end it really depends on how you prefer to work. Dual Boot is good if you need the full capacity of the Linux OS (say you are running some CPU intensive program on the Mint side) - then dual-boot may be more beneficial. If you only plan to use Mint as general use and not running anything intensive - then running it as a VM is probably better as you mentioned that you can access both side of the OS (Win and Linux).

Comment: Did you get it working?  I can't get hyper-v display drivers to load and there's little information online that I can find.  The software rendering driver is super-slow.

Comment: It's working, but it's "running in software rendering mode". I have not yet been able to resolve this.